# Free software to read .cbr files

Tags: windows, cbr

Can anyone recommend a free comic book reader (for the .cbr format) for Windows?

Comment: Good question .. voted +

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CBR is a RAR format. You can simply rename the file with the RAR extension and use any RAR uncompresser. There is an open source comic book reader [CDisplayEx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDisplayEx) that some people use.

Comment: That WP link is broken, use http://sourceforge.net/projects/cdisplayex/ instead.

Comment: not that bad. What I don't like: if I press DownArrow, the page scrolls down to the middle of the page, and that's too low...

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is [ComicRack](http://comicrack.cyolito.com/).
It has lots of features (besides .CBR support), though at first it may seem a bit overwhelming. YMMV.

Comment: I tried ComicRack, but in my opinion, it was buggy.

Comment: and you need .NET-framework 4.0 for this

Answer (score 0):

I like [Honeyview](http://www.honeyview.org/).
Honeyview also has a portable version.

Disadvantage: Honeyview takes about (10 * size_of_cbr_file) MB of RAM while running...